# System::String^ to Hexadecimal representation, help needed

Tags: visual-c++

I need to convert String^ type to hexadecimal string representation. I'm coding on MSVC++'05. Need help with the algorithm, have already tried the strtol function and it is not outputting the result i'm expecting.

```
String^ str = "993";
```

I wan str to be converted to hexadecimal which is 0x03E1, how do i go about do this? Any help or directions is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Int32(Int32::Parse(str)).ToString("x")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforming it into a hexadecimal is in the display portion of it.

```
String^ str = "993";
int value;
if(!Int32::TryParse(str,value))
{
    Console::WriteLine("Failed, exiting");
    return -1;
}
Console::WriteLine(value.ToString("X"));
```

This indicates the output should be hex -----^^^

Comment: Hi, thanks for the swift response. But i'm not intending to output via console but instead store it as a variable and pass the hexa representation as an argument to whichever function that requires it. So i can't depend lon the Console::WriteLine() right? Any alternative method which you know? ;) Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user714826 Are you talking about converting the string to a hexadecimal string?  The representation of the integer in the system is in binary, the rest of it is just window dressing.  All you need to do it pass in the integer, then.

Comment: Apologize if i didn't make myself clear, yup, from a string to a hexadecimal string. :)

Comment: @user714826 Okay, in that case, just replace the last line of the code with `String^ hextring = value.ToString("X");`.  Then pass in hexstring.